# what does the "modules" part of the manifest.json file do (minecraft bedrock edition resource packs)

Tags: minecraft

What is the 'modules' part of the manifest.json file? The Minecraft wiki does not explain what it does.

Also, I have been told to write my question here on meta stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This section describes the modules that comprise the pack. Each entry here defines one of the kinds of contents of the pack.

From https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Bedrock_Edition_add-on_documentation

It defines the type of pack you make, so the game knows how to treat it. For example:

```
"type": "resources"
```

will let the game know it's a resourcepack.

> ...and define the "type" to be "resources". This makes your pack a Resource Pack, also called a Client pack or a Texture pack. It changes things in-game visually.

> it is very much like a Resource pack manifest, except the "type" is "data"(for a Data Pack/Behavior Pack)

(From https://sites.google.com/view/mcbe-add-on-tutorial/-/manifest-function)

Can be any of the following: resources, data, client_data, interface, world_template

Hope it answers your question.